# How to set the order property after sorting with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a knockout object (menu) and I want to sort that menu with drag and drop. I found jQuery Sortable that is a nice plugin so you could sort a list in your dom. But how do I bind that order against the knockout object order property? I can't use the $index property of knockout because the array isn't adjusted.

I've created a fiddle so you could see an example.
It must be possible that the menu is nested like in this fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhkZW/1)

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: people" class='example'>
<li>
    Knockout position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span><br />
    Item name: <span data-bind="text: name"> </span><br />
    Order that I want to save in database: <span data-bind="text: order"> </span>

    <ol></ol>
</li>
```

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.people = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Item A', order: 1 },
    { name: 'Item B', order: 2 },
    { name: 'Item C', order: 3 }
]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

$(function  () {
$("ol.example").sortable({
    onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {
        $item.removeClass("dragged").removeAttr("style");
        $("body").removeClass("dragging");

        // Set the order property of the person right in the ui here????            
    }
});
})


body.dragging, body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.example li.placeholder {
   position: relative;
   /** More li styles **/
}
ol.example li.placeholder:before {
   position: absolute;
   /** Define arrowhead **/
}
```

Comment: Link of the sortable plugin: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this plugin that I wrote: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable. It has some configurability along with having dealt with many of the issues that come with integrating with the sortable functionality.

Comment: I know that plugin. I tryed it with the jquery accordion as nested but that was to heavy and buggy. So I started over and found the plugin above. I used that plugin because I couldn't find any sample of the jquery ui sortable with nested lists... Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Sure- you can do nested lists like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Lqttf/.  If you only wanted to sort within the same level, then you can use the "connectClass" option to make sure that you can't sort between lists of different levels like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/yXYQp/.

Comment: Hi, Ryan, If you place your comment as an answer, I will accept it as answer. The links in your last comment worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [knockout-sortable](http://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) library handles keeping a sortable section in sync with an observableArray.  You can also have nested sortable lists.

If you do not want to be able to drop items from one level into another, then you can use the `connectClass` option to restrict which other sortables can participate with it.

Comment: This library helped me a lot! The page is finished and everything works fine now!